# Spring batch file reading: JBOSS EAP 6.2 File encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, jboss, spring-batch

**JBOSS EAP 6.2 :**

In JBOSS file encoding has already mentioned in standalone.conf.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Currently file format is changed form "UTF-8" to "ISO-8859-1".

How I can modify it? What is the default file encoding in JBOSS?

Spring batch read the file and write into database.

Comment: How do you write the file?

Comment: I am write the file into oracle database

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thank you for replying this. It is not related to code. It is configuration related change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.standalone.conf need to be modified like below. I thought this might be an answer, But it was not mentioned anywhere when I searched in the internet.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1"
```

This will set in Java JVM file encoding. So , File will be encoded by java accordingly

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html